# ¿Hay forma de comparar la estructura de 2 bases de datos en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 bases de datos que tendrían que ser idénticas.
Una la tengo en el servidor de mi cliente y otra la tengo en mi servidor (esta última para hacer pruebas cuando solicitan alguna modificación).

El tema es que le hice una modificación al sistema y a ellos les arroja `null reference exception` y a mí me funciona perfecto, lo que no estoy seguro es si es por un problema de código o por inconsistencia de la `DB`, es por eso que quiero saber si hay alguna forma de comparar si ambas bases de datos tienen las mismas tablas con los mismos campos.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Presupones un problema de estructura, pero un `null reference exception`, puede bien ser un problema de datos. Antes de mirar el tema estructura yo miraría bien el error, dónde lo da particularmente.

Comment: Supongo que es un problema de estructura porque probandolo en mi servidor no tengo ningún problema... por eso quiero descartar que sea problema de la base

Comment: Hay varias maneras. Puedes hacer queries a las tablas de sistemas. Puedes utilizar SQLServer Management Studio para revisar las tablas, columnas, índices, etc.; o, si necesitas una herramienta, puedes utilizar [Sql Compare de RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/). Pero para responder a tu pregunta: Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? **Sí. Sí la hay.**

Comment: Te entiendo, pero el camino que eliges no necesariamente va a darte una respuesta, tal vez tengas diferencias en las estructuras, que no sean la causa de este error, primero debes buscar la causa analizando el error, ¿Dónde se da? ¿Qué hace el código en ese momento? Ahora si simplemente quieres comparar estructuras, una forma bien simple y gratis es exportar a un script las estructuras de las dos bases y compararlas con un diff tipo e Winmerge o similar.

Comment: A que te refieres con "hice una modificación al sistema", donde en que ? porque solo veo referencias sobre SQL. cuéntanos en que momento le da error al usuario

Comment: Clásico [Problema X -> Y](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY)

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si hace falta agregar un plug-in especial o si viene integrado con Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise (la versión que tengo instalada) pero desde el explorador de objetos de SQL Server que se muestra desde el menu vista. (Edición: Acabo de revisar que también funciona en la edición Community que está incluida de forma gratuita como beneficio de [VS Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/))

[image: Mostrar Explorador de Objetos de SQL Server]

Al conectarte a una instancia, puedes dar click derecho en la base de datos y escoger comparar esquema (o datos pero eso es demasiado pesado).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te abre el comparador y seleccionas la base de datos de origen y la de destino.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te mostrará un reporte y puedes seleccionar los objetos que quieras crear, modificar o eliminar en la base de datos destino para que queden con la misma estructura.

Comment: es una buena respuesta.. siempre y cuando tenga vs 2022...  que use sql server no implica que tenga vs 2022...

Comment: Claro, la solución es dependiente de una herramienta. Acabo de revisar y también está incluida en la edición Community que puede descargar de forma gratuita (y legal)

Comment: siempre y cuando.. este programando desde windows.. no? ;) (igual la respuesta no es mala.. pero tiene muchos peros que mejor hubiera sido preguntarlos)... es mas.. fijate en todos los comentarios...